# How to extract second group from second item of list from a regexp pattern in tcl

Tags: tcl

How to extract the second group from the second item of the list.
I'm printing all results to see.

Extract the date from this:

```
<span class="rel_date">26 Sep at 12:18 am</span>
```

```
(...)
    set result [regexp -inline -all -line {(?:class="rel_date">)(.*)(?:<\/sp)} [http::data $token]]
    foreach j $result {
        foreach {group0 group1 group2} $j {
        puts $group1
        }       
    }
(...)
```

Comment: Parsing HTML with regexes is inherently dodgy. You might want to look at the [`htmlparse`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcllib/htmlparse.html) package in tcllib.

Comment: @glennjackman I don't understand how htmlparse works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You don't need the outer `foreach`:

```
set result [regexp -inline -all -line {(?:class="rel_date">)(.*)(?:<\/sp)} [http::data $token]]
foreach {group0 group1} $result {
    puts $group1
    # => 26 Sep at 12:18 am
}
```

There is really only two groups in the results. One containing the main match, the second containing the first capture group (`( ... )` is a capture group, but `(?: ... )` is not)

If you happen to have many such spans in the same page, then the above loop will still work:

```
set page {
    <span class="rel_date">26 Sep at 12:18 am</span>
    <span class="rel_date">26 Sep at 12:19 am</span>
}

set result [regexp -inline -all -line {(?:class="rel_date">)(.*)(?:<\/sp)} $page]
foreach {group0 group1} $result {
    puts $group1
}
# => 26 Sep at 12:18 am
# => 26 Sep at 12:19 am
```